# Split one table into multiple table based on one column

Tags: python, pandas

Given a table (/dataFrame) x:

```
name    day earnings    revenue
Oliver   1   100         44
Oliver   2   200         69
John     1   144         11
John     2   415         54
John     3   33          10
John     4   82          82
```

Is it possible to split the table into two tables based on the name column (that acts as an index), and nest the two tables under the same object (not sure about the exact terms to use). So in the example above, `tables[0]` will be:

```
name    day earnings    revenue
Oliver  1   100         44
Oliver  2   200         69
```

and `tables[1]` will be:

```
name    day earnings    revenue
John    1   144         11
John    2   415         54
John    3   33          10
John    4   82          82
```

Note that that the number of rows in each 'sub-table' may vary.

Cheers,

Comment: Have you tried to solve this using a loop and normal pandas filtering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create dictionary of DataFrames:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('name')))
```

And then select by keys - value of `name` column:

```
print (dfs['Oliver'])
print (dfs['John'])
```

Comment: Works great!! thanks!